# Beeping sound coming from Windows system while Adobe software open

Tags: windows, adobe-premiere, adobe-after-effects

Recently there has appeared a beeping sound while I have Adobe After effects and Premiere running. I seems to be on a regular interval with 2-3 seconds in between and sounds similar to metronome sounds I've heard in audio software.

I have concluded that it comes from the system and that it stops when closing the Adobe programs. After searching for answers I came across a thread saying hard drives can make warning sounds when they are about to die. Could that be the case here since these programs sometimes push the hard drives for cache purposes? If not, any other thoughts?

I'd be very greatful for any help!

Comment: From your question it is hard to tell what it could be but one possibility is coil whine which can be audible on some setups. If it's a desktop then try running with the case open to see if you can pinpoint the source. To verify whether the hard drive is failing you can use a tool like SpeedFan.

Comment: Thanks for your input! 

Thing is it's not a random-ish noise like coil whine, but an audio file beep being played at a regular interval. I remembered after reading your comment that I do have Speedfan installed for controlling my fans, but after doing my hard drive checks they both seem to be doing just fine, so I'm pretty much back to square one.. 

Any more ideas anyone?

Comment: Possibly your graphics card (if you have one) or something else isn't getting enough power, some component can give audible warnings in that situation.